# "Preserve log" in Chrome Console to see "Uncaught TypeError"?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I uncheck "Preserve log" in the console settings, I don't see the error below. Why are they related?

---

[image]

Comment: Because the page is refreshing....

Comment: @epascarello If *refreshing* is the reason then it should eventually show up after a little while. It doesn't.

Comment: Why? The error occurs, page refreshes....  It is like saying I had a message on a whiteboard, it should reappear after I erase it. Clicking that button keeps the app from erasing the whiteboard.

Comment: @epascarello I see -- got it, thanks! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **Preserve Log** is enabled, the Console preserves messages until you explicitly clear it. When it's disabled, the Console clears messages on page loads.

So, it looks like there's some code that runs *just before* you navigate to a new page, and that code is throwing an error. So while the error technically does get displayed (for a split-second) in both scenarios, it's probably just getting erased before you can see it with your eyes when you have **Preserve Log** disabled.